# Android Studio app circular profile pic image

Tags: xml, android-studio, user-profile

Good morning,

the latest thing I am trying to do with my app is to make a profile image appear circular.  It is currently in 'match parent' form and fills the whole screen and I'd like to display a whatsapp type circular image.  What is the best way of doing this?

This is my current xml:

```
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.nalexanderdev.runcommunity.activities.ProfileActivity">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Profile"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/nameField"
    android:hint="Name"
    android:layout_above="@+id/emailField"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/emailField"
    android:hint="Email@mail.com"
    android:layout_above="@+id/cancelBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Cancel"
    android:id="@+id/cancelBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Update"
    android:id="@+id/updateBtn"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/emailField" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/selectImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="Select Image From Gallery" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/selectImage"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    app:srcCompat="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled" />
</RelativeLayout>`
```

Comment: There are many resources on how to achieve that. https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=circular+imageview+android or https://www.google.pl/search?q=circular+image+view+android

Answer (score 0):

**Replace your ImageView with the CircleImageView.**

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_below="@+id/selectImage"
            app:srcCompat="@color/common_google_signin_btn_text_light_disabled" 
            android:id="@+id/imageView2" 
            app:civ_border_color="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:civ_border_width="1dp
              />
```

And add   compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0' to your gradle dependencies.